# Flattening quantification over relations

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, higher-order-logic

I already asked this question in [stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554326/flattening-quantification-over-relations) and somebody suggested to post it here. I repeat the question again:

I have a Relation f defined as $f: A \to B × C$. I would like to write a first-order formula to constraint this relation to be a bijective function from A to B × C?

To be more precise, I would like the first order counter part of the following formula (actually conjunction of the three):

$$\begin{align}
\forall a: A,\exists! bc : B × C, f(a)=bc   & \qquad\text{$f$ is function}\\
\forall a_1,a_2: A, f(a_1)=f(a_2) → a_1=a_2       & \qquad\text{$f$ is injective}\\
\forall bc : B × C, \exists a : A, f(a)=bc   & \qquad\text{ $f$ is surjective}
\end{align}
$$

As you see the above formulae are in Higher Order Logic as I quantified over the relations. What is the first-order logic equivalent of these formulae if it is ever possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can write it in first-order set theory, with the predicate $\in$ ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: [The axioms of set theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html) are formalized in first order language : functions and relations are sets and sets are the objects of the domain of quantification; so, when we quantify a variable we quantify sets (like $B \times C$) and functions (like $f$)...

Comment: This problem comes from the application domain. Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516434/converting-higher-order-expression-into-alloy-first-order-logic). so, I can not consider B * C as a pure set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of al in logic $ B \times C$ is just an other set.

so lets assume

- Ax is true iff  $ x \in A$
- Bx is true iff $  x \in B \times C$
- Rxy is true iff $  f(x) = y $

then your relations become

$f(x)$ is a function: $ \forall x (Ax \to ( \exists y (By \land Rxy \land \forall z ((Bz \land Rxz) \to y = z )))) $

$f(x)$ is injective: $ \forall x y z ((Ax \land Ay \land Bz \land Rxz \land Ryz ) \to x = y)  $

the last one you can do yourself

GOOD LUCK

Comment: Probably the third part then would be: $f(x)$ is surjective: $ \forall x ( Bx \to \exists y(Ay \land Ryx))$ Am I right?

Comment: [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516434/converting-higher-order-expression-into-alloy-first-order-logic) the encoding of this formula in alloy where the original problem arose.

Comment: looks okay, ps i do think the combination of function, injective and surjective together can be simplified (I think  that if $f$ is a function and $f$ is surjective then $f$ is injective ) but i do need to check this myself first. as answer I wanted to split the conditions into seperate formula's, ps i don't know alloy so can not check youranswer at stackoverflow